# Redirect stdout to a file

Tags: c, redirect, pipe, posix

I am trying to do the equivalent of the bash command `ls>foo.txt` in C.

The code bellow redirects the output to a variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
  int pfds[2];
  char buf[30];

  pipe(pfds);

  if (!fork()) {
    close(pfds[0]);
     //close(1);//Close stdout
    //dup(pfds[1]);
    //execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    write(pfds[1], "test", 5); //Writing in the pipe
    exit(0);
  } else {
    close(pfds[1]);  
    read(pfds[0], buf, 5); //Read from pipe
    wait(NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The comments lines refer to those operations that I believe that are required for the redirection.
What should I change to redirect the output of ls to foo.txt?

Comment: Why are you creating a pipe when there's no pipe shown in the shell syntax you're emulating?

Comment: "Equivalent to [this bash code] in C" doesn't make it a bash question. Only tag it bash if you want people who are experts in bash (and not C!) to look at it.

Comment: If you want to redirect stdout to a file, you would like to write your print like `fprintf(stdout,...);` I mean, to have "stdout" still written in your code, but redirected to a file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What your code essentially does is that you open a pipe, then fork the process and in the child process (in commented code) close stdout, duplicate the pipe to stdout and execute and ls command, and then (in non-commented code) write 4 bytes to the pipe. In the parent process, you read data from the pipe and wait for the completion of the child process.

Now you want to redirect stdout to a file. You can do that by opening a file using the open() system call and then duplicating that file descriptor to stdout. Something like (I haven't tested this so beware of bugs in the code):

```
int filefd = open("foo.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
if (!fork()) {
  close(1);//Close stdout
  dup(filefd);
  execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
} else {
  close(filefd);
  wait(NULL);
}
return 0;
```

However, you can also use the freopen as suggested by the other answer.

However, I have several concerns of your code and of my modified code:

- The pipe() and open() system calls can fail. You should always check for system call failure.
- The fork() system call can fail. Ditto.
- dup2() can be used instead of dup(); otherwise the code will fail if stdin is not open as it duplicates to the first available file descriptor.
- The execlp() system call can fail. Ditto.
- I think wait() can be interrupted by a signal (EINTR). It's recommended to wrap it around a wrapper that retries the system call if it's aborted by a signal (errno == EINTR).

Answer (score 27):

While dealing with redirecting output to a file you may use [freopen().](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/)

Assuming you are trying to redirect your `stdout` to a file '**output.txt**' then you can write-

```
freopen("output.txt", "a+", stdout);
```

Here "`a+`" for append mode. If the file exists then the file open in append mode. Otherwise a new file is created.

After reopening the `stdout` with `freopen()` all output statement (printf, putchar) are redirected to the 'output.txt'. So after that any `printf()` statement will redirect it's output to the **'output.txt'** file.

If you want to resume `printf()`'s default behavior again (that is printing in terminal/command prompt) then you have to reassign `stdout` again using the following code-

```
freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout); /*for gcc, ubuntu*/
```

Or -

```
freopen("CON", "w", stdout); /*Mingw C++; Windows*/
```

However similar technique works for '`stdin`'.

Comment: I am testing it over Linux and FreeBSD on a process spawned by using `fork()` , and the `output.txt` file is created, but receives no text. Is this supposed to work in these cases? Or maybe there is no `stdout` stream on a spawned process? Perhaps some sort of redirection would be needed?

Comment: Do we need to `fclose(stdout)` BEFORE such operations?

Do we need to `fclose(stdout)` AFTER such operations?

Answer (score 0):

"tested using terminal in ubuntu" .

say for example your code is "mike.c"
you first compile it by

```
gcc mike.c
```

if there are no errors,
you then do

```
./a.out > file
```

you shall find your file containing the code in the same directory (folder) as mike.c

Note that file could be (file.txt, file.md ...)

hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).