# dup2 not switching to file?

Tags: c, file, dup2

I'm trying to learn `dup2` and switch the stdout to a file rather than terminal. This is the example that works everywhere but not sure why it is not working for me. I don't think I need a fork() because I don't need a different process for execute just the print statement in file.

Where function is called:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *something = "hello";
  saveHistoryToFile(something);
}
```

//This is the function. There is a file names history .txt

```
void saveHistoryToFile(char *history){
  int fw = open("history.txt",O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
  dup2(fw, 1);
  printf("%s", history);
}
```

THE ERROR: it prints into terminal not file!

Comment: What exactly does "not working for me" mean?  Doesn't compile?  Crashes at runtime? Produces the wrong result?

Comment: Looks OK to me as long as `"history.txt"` exists, otherwise add `O_CREAT`. Error checking + `perror` or running under `strace` should reveal what the problem is.

Comment: Does `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` fix it?

Comment: it does not print into a file just prints into terminal @JohnBollinger

Comment: You are not checking the return values of your function calls so as to recognize whether they succeed.  Chances are good that your call to `open()` is failing, and as a result, your call to `dup2()` is failing as well.  That would leave you with the standard output still connected to the terminal (or whatever else it was originally connected to).

Comment: if(!fw){perror("FILE NOT FOUND)");} is not giving me any error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154056/redirect-stdout-to-a-file)

Comment: I don't see why you would expect `if (!fw)` to detect errors, since `open` returns -1 on error, and -1 is truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int saveHistoryToFile(char *history);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *something = "hello";
  if(0>saveHistoryToFile(something)) return 1;
  if(0>fclose(stdout)) return perror("fclose"),-1;
}

int saveHistoryToFile(char *history){
  int fw = open("history.txt",O_WRONLY | O_APPEND /*|O_CREAT, 0640*/ );
  if (0>fw) return perror("open"),-1;
  if (0>dup2(fw, 1)) return perror("dup2"),-1;
  if (0>(printf("%s", history)))  return perror("printf"),-1;
}
```

On a first run, I get "open: No such file or directory" because I do not have `"history.txt"` in my current directory.

If I add it or uncomment the `O_CREAT, 0640`, it runs fine on my machine.

Of course, you might run into other problems (e.g, `EPERM`) but the `perror`s should give you a hint.

Comment: This is giving me Permission denied

Comment: on open in function

Comment: @BassamMetwally And can you not troubleshoot that? What's your current directory what are its permissions  (try running `system("stat \"$PWD\" history.txt");`).

Comment: @BassamMetwally You also need a mode argument with the `O_CREAT` flag. I had forgotten that one.

Comment: YES! this worked THANK YOU. I just ran chmod to allow for writing and reading.