# How to get only the return value of a function in c?

Tags: c, function

I declare a function with both `printf` in the body and a return value,how can i only get the return value without `printf` the things inside the body(I want to use 1 function for both things: `printf` and return value separately)

```
int number (int i)
{
    printf("Hi,I just want to print this");
    return (i+1);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d%*c", &i);
    printf("The number plus 1 is: %d\n", number(i));
    number (i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show the code that you have (instead of describing it)

Comment: You're asking how to run a function with a side effect without the side effect?

Comment: Your function should just return a value. Then you can call it and print out that value when you want to do that.

Comment: you can't, if your function returns a value, it's always going to return a value. If you only want to `printf` sometimes, there will need to be some logic indicating when to do that. Passing a bool flag to the function, for instance.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is possibly [redirecting stdout somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29154056/10077).

Comment: Can i only write it in only 1 function?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please describe step by step what's the result you're interested in

Comment: If you are allowed to change `number()` function interface, the solution is really trivial, and it is explained in @yano ' comment.

Comment: You can't get the return value of function without calling it.  You can't call half a function.

Comment: Sometimes (*sometimes!*) it's appropriate to pass in a "verbose" flag to a function, to tell it whether to print its noisy messages or not.  Most of the time, though, it ends up being really nice if every function "does one job and does it well".  Mode flags detract from that.  And most of the time, functions that are noisy are a real nuisance -- we get gobs of questions here about how to redirect `stdout` in order to suppress a badly-written function's noisy messages.  So my advice to you, if you can, is to have the function not print anything, and put all the printing in the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create two separate functions:

```
void PrintFnc (void)
{
  printf("Hi,I just want to print this");
}

int NumberFunc (int i)
{
  return (i+1);
}
```

Or control the function with a bool:

```
int BothFunc (int i, bool shouldPrint)
{
  if (shouldPrint) {
    printf("Hi,I just want to print this");
  }
  return (i+1);
}
```

Comment: How can i just write in only 1 function for both things?

Comment: @PhmHiu You say in your question you don't want both things.

Comment: i want to do both things but seperately for example when i use printf("%d", number(i)),it will also print out the body which i don't want to see

Comment: @PhmHiu just use my second example, it will do what you wan't. However seems like what you really want is the printf to be somewhere else.

Comment: @PhmHiu I suggest you give an example of your desired output, as I understand your question, the solution of Fredrik should work.