# Get the last string printed in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, string, output, googletest

I am trying to create a tester using googletest. the problem is that the function that I am testing is returning void and printing a result instead. I want to get the last string printed into the console so I can test the output. the string may include `\n`.

so I have the function itself:

```c
void f_sequence(char sequenceStr[])
{
   //logic...
    if(condotion1)
        printf("somthing1");
    else if(condotion2)
        printf("somthing2")
(...)
}
```

and then the tester:

```cpp
TEST(TesterGroup, TesterName)
{
    f_sequence("input");
    EXPECT_EQ("somthing1", /*how do i get the output?*/);
}
```

Is it possible?

The functions I test are in c, while the Test function itself (the tester) is in c++. the output is printed using `printf`. I cannot change the function itself. I am using CLion latest version.

Comment: Can you change the function so it accepts a `std::ostream&` parameter instead of just printing to stdout/stderr?

Comment: c or c++ ? They are different languages and solutions will differ substantially. (and there is no language called C/C++, thats a unfortunately commonly used misnomer)

Comment: @idclev463035818 The functions I test are in c, while the Test function itself (the tester) is in c++

Comment: @avivgood2 -- post some (minimal) code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @jtbandes It is printed using printf and I can't change it, just write the testers

Comment: not my topic to help with, but still you should provide a [mcve]. Details do matter

Comment: You can [redirect stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29154056/673852) and then read from that file when your C function returns.

Comment: This function isn't testable as is. I would recommend @jtbandes suggestion.

Comment: There is source code [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188630/send-command-and-get-response-from-windows-cmd-prompt-silently-follow-up) (for Windows applications only) that creates an API for sending a cmd and reading `stdout` into a dynamically sizing buffer.  I have tested it up to 2GBytes when reading a recursive directory call to Windows.  ( [Here is the original](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162546/send-command-and-get-response-from-windows-cmd-prompt-silently), before review. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect the standard output to a buffer.

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3f030cec439264)</kbd>**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
int stdoutSave;
char outputBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void replaceStdout()
{
    fflush(stdout); //clean everything first
    stdoutSave = dup(STDOUT_FILENO); //save the stdout state
    freopen("NUL", "a", stdout); //redirect stdout to null pointer
    setvbuf(stdout, outputBuffer, _IOFBF, 1024); //set buffer to stdout
}

void restoreStdout()
{
    freopen("NUL", "a", stdout); //redirect stdout to null again
    dup2(stdoutSave, STDOUT_FILENO); //restore the previous state of stdout
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFFER_SIZE); //disable buffer to print to screen instantly
}

void printHelloWorld()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    printf("world");
}

int main()
{
    replaceStdout();
    printHelloWorld();
    restoreStdout();
    // Use outputBuffer to test EXPECT_EQ("somthing1", outputBuffer);
    printf("Fetched output: (%s)", outputBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

References: http://kaskavalci.com/redirecting-stdout-to-array-and-restoring-it-back-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to get what was last printed, but if you control the environment *before* your test function is called, you can redirect where standard output goes, which lets you write it to a file, which you can then check.

See [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21136532/83839) which IMO was neglected.  The example from it is modified here:

```
FILE *fp_old = stdout;  // preserve the original stdout
stdout = fopen("/path/to/file/you/want.txt","w");  // redirect stdout to anywhere you can open
// CALL YOUR FUNCTION UNDER TEST HERE
fclose(stdout);  // Close the file with the output contents
stdout=fp_old;  // restore stdout to normal

// Re-open the file from above, and read it to make sure it contains what you expect.
```

Comment: Why not simply `freopen`?

Comment: @Ruslan I'm not sure if `freopen()` will preserve the original standard output stream, or if it will actually close standard output, and you can't get it back (easily), which in a testing environment is probably bad.

Comment: @KevinAnderson using stdout as an l-value is not portable though...

Comment: Fair enough.  More discussion on options for this type of thing here: http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

If you're on a POSIX compatibile system, you can redirect the output of the program to a file using `>`, then read from the file later to confirm that the output is correct.

The other way is something like this:

```
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
f_sequence();
freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
```

for POSIX compatible systems. On other platforms you'd need to change the `"/dev/tty"` to something else. I'm not aware of a completely portable way to do this.

And then read from `output.txt`. What the above snippet does is change what `stdout` is, so that it prints to a file instead of the normal stdout.

Comment: Why not simply `freopen`?

Comment: Actually, I don't think you can save the original `stdout` this way... `freopen` will modify the pointee.

Comment: @Ruslan you're right. I'm not sure the 100% portable way to do this however..

Comment: As for the first option, how can I redirect the output to a file? (I am using CLion). and how can I read from the output file via code?

Comment: I would recommend the second option since the first involves compiling your function seperately and executing that (unless I'm missing something)..

Comment: Ooooooh, not as fun then lol. Go with the second way, first way won't really work on Windows.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso in the second option, where am I getting the string? into what variable?

Comment: the output which would normally be printed with printf is instead put into a file named `output.txt`. You just read from that file...

Comment: if the file is saved in output.txt then what is the line ```freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);``` is for? (sorry for the multiple questions, I am just trying to understand the code)

Comment: @avivgood2 that is to restore `stdout` to its old value after you're done. Since you're on Windows you probably don't want `/dev/tty` though. Not sure what the Windows one is...

Answer (score 0):

One solution: You can write a separate program that executes the function, and in the unit test, you can execute that program as a sub process and inspect the output. This can be done with `std::system`, but be very careful to not pass any non-constant input to it. You don't want shell injection vulnerability even in a unit test. System specific functions exist that avoid the use of shell in the subprocess.

Another solution, which is possible at least on POSIX: Replace the the standard out / err streams with file descriptors, and read the files afterwards.

Googletest specific: There seems to be `testing::internal::CaptureStdout`, which appears to implement the idea of replacing standard streams. But as the namespace implies, this is not official API, so may change in future.

Comment: Me and Kevin have both already suggested both of these options...

Comment: `system(3)` is a standard way to execute subprocesses.

Comment: @Ruslan I've learned to disregard it because of its inherent unsafety. But I suppose that's not critical here as long as there is no user input.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Congratulations on being a fast typist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution ( in `C` ) for an API call ( `cmd_rsp` ) [with source code here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162546/send-command-and-get-response-from-windows-cmd-prompt-silently), that when called in your program, creates a separate process, and pipes to both `stdin` and `stdout`, from which it accepts a  command and returns the response via an auto sizing buffer. Similar in concept to `popen(...)`.

A simple use case:

```
char *buf = NULL;

/// test cmd_rsp
buf = calloc(BUF_SIZE, 1);
if(!buf)return 0;
if (!cmd_rsp("dir /s", &buf, BUF_SIZE))//note the first argument can be any legal command that 
                                       //can be sent via the CMD prompt in windows, 
                                       //including a custom executable
{
    printf("%s", buf);
}
else
{
    printf("failed to send command.\n");
}
free(buf);
```