# Why is it not possible to replace stdout with pipe output directly?

Tags: c, pipe, stdout

I want to pipe the output of a child process to the parent's `stdout`. I know there are other ways of doing this, but why can't a pipe's read-end be duplicated to `stdout`? **Why** doesn't the program print what is written to the pipes write end?

Here i have a minimal example (without any subprocesses) of what I'm trying to do. Im expecting to see `test` in the output when running, but the program outputs nothing.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int fds[2];
    if(pipe(fds) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(write(fds[1], "test", 5) == -1) {
        perror("write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(dup2(fds[0], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
        perror("dup2");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` prior to `dup2`. Also you should check if `dup2` fails (`if dup2(fds[0], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {handle error}`).

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO` is inherited by the child (forked?) process. Why not write directly to `STDOUT_FILENO` in the child?

Comment: @Jabberwocky dup2() automatically closes STDOUT_FILENO. That would be true if i used dup().

Comment: @tstanisl It's not a question of how to fix, I'm more wondering why this is not possible.

Comment: so the question is about joining two **existing** file descriptors into a pipe?

Comment: @tstanisl Well, to my understanding this is; creating a pipe, and replacing the stdout file descriptor with the pipe's read end. Why doesn't the program print what is written to the pipes write end?

Comment: `stdout` is an output stream, but `fds[0]` is open for reading.  `fclose(stdout)` is going to fail.

Comment: You need two processes. One reads from a pipe, one writes to a pipe. A single process can create a pipe, but until there is another process that does something with the other end, the pipe is useless. And that other process cannot be the parent of the process that created the pipe, because the parent process knows nothing about file descriptors that the child opens.

Comment: does this link help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29154056/4989451 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipe is two “files” that share a buffer and some locking or control semantics. When you write into the pipe, the data is put into the buffer. When you read from a pipe, the data is taken from a buffer.

There is nothing in the pipe that moves data to some output device.

If you use `dup2` to duplicate the read side of the pipe into the standard output file descriptor (number 1), then all you have is the read side of the pipe on file descriptor 1. That means you can issue read operations to file descriptor 1, and the system will give your program data from the pipe.

There is nothing “special” about file descriptor 1 in this regard. Putting any file on file descriptor 1 does not cause that file to be automatically sent anywhere. The way standard output works normally is that you open a terminal or some chosen output file or other device on file descriptor 1, and then you send things to that device or file by writing to file descriptor 1. The operating system does not automatically write things to file descriptor 1; you have to issue write operations.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! How does the parent-child relation work? By default, a childs stdout gets forwarded into the parents. You mean this cannot be implemented with a pipe? How else is this done?

Comment: @Olle: When a process is forked, the child and the parent simply have the same files open. It is not a matter of the child’s standard output being forwarded into the parent’s. If the parent has its standard output (file descriptor 1) open to a terminal or a file when it forks, then the child has its standard output (file descriptor 1) open to the same terminal or file.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!