# Python - want to log to file but NOT to console

Tags: python, logging, console

I would like to do the opposite of what often people are stuck with (they cannot get the logging to the console). I would like to log to file or GUI (that's not a problem) but I want to suppress the log to the console. So, question, how do I log ONLY to file and NOT to Console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154056/redirect-stdout-to-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

I have written for my own purposes following function:

```
def stdoutOf(strToExec): 
    import io, sys; ioS = io.StringIO() # create file like string
    stdout = sys.stdout # save sys.stdout to restore it later on
    sys.stdout = ioS # redirect stdout to the string
    exec(strToExec) # some code to run with stdout written to a string
    sys.stdout = stdout # restore sys.stdout
    ioS.seek(0)
    return ioS.read() # get what was written to stdout
#:stdout_of()
```

from which you can take the code if you need to process the error messages before writing them to the file or use the method described here [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python#4675744) and nailed down to `with open(‘filename.ext’, ‘w’) as sys.stdout:` as your question has already an answer on stackoverflow.