# Connecting pipes to stin & stout in C

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

I'm working on an assignment whereby I create a program called jobthing, which  creates and manages processes according to a job specification file. Part of the requirements are:

• If an input file is specified for the job, jobthing shall attempt to open that file in read mode and the job is to have its stdin redirected from that file. Otherwise, jobthing shall create a pipe, connecting that job’s stdin to the reading end of the pipe, with jobthing holding the write end of the pipe through which it will later send information.

• Similarly, if an output file is specified for the job, jobthing shall attempt to open that file in for writing and the job is to have its stdout redirected to that file. Otherwise, jobthing shall create a pipe, connecting that job’s stdout to the writing end of the pipe, with jobthing holding the read end of the pipe through which it will later receive information.

I've managed to write the correct code to read input/output files and redirect the stdin & stdout as required, but I'm really struggling on the code for when no input/output file is specified, and creating the pipes to connect the stdin/stout to jobthing. In the code below, when input/output isn't "", it recognises there's a file and redirects as needed. Any help on how to create the pipes when there's no file would be amazing!

```
/**
 * Redirects input and output of job process to given valid filename.
 *
 * @param input filename of file to redirect input from 
 * @param output filename of file to redirect output to 
 */ 
void redirect(char* input, char* output) {
    if (strcmp(input, "") != 0) {
        int newInput = open(input, O_RDONLY); 
        dup2(newInput, 0); 
        close(newInput); 
    } 
    if (strcmp(output, "") != 0) {
        int newOutput = open(output, O_WRONLY); 
        dup2(newOutput, 1); 
        close(newOutput); 
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to add a check for the pointer not being `NULL`. Then you don't need `strcmp` to check if a string is "empty", just check if the first character is the terminator or not. Thirdly, *always* check for error from functions that can fail, most notably the `open` call. What happens if `open` fails?

Comment: As for the pipes, it's unclear how the pipes should be used. Are you just going to be connecting standard output to standard input, so anything you write on `STDOUT_FILENO` will be possible to read on `STDIN_FILENO`? What should happen if only `input` is "empty"? Or only `output`?

Comment: Sounds like there are other requirements like `"stdin redirected from that file."` and for output files `"have its stdout redirected to that file."` Do you have anything written yet that would show where you are stuck? See [Redirect stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29154056/3422102) for ideas on handling redirection to/from a file.

Comment: Thank you for your message! I'll make some amendments to cater for that! With the pipes, if the input string is 'empty' then the job in question would receive it's standard input from a pipe connected to the jobthing program itself (jobthing creates pipe, connecting the jobs stdout to the writing end with jobthing holding the read end). If the output is 'empty', job sends standard output to a pipe connected to jobthing (jobthing creates pipe, connecting the jobs stdout to writing end of the pipe, with jobthing holding the read end). That's the part I'm really struggling on! Hope it makes sense